# How can I pass multiple bitwise values in PHP function?

Tags: php, bitwise-operators

I have a function having multiple parameter containing True/False in them like

`function checkPersonStatus($isEmployed, $isResident, $isDisable, $isMarried)`

I want to convert these into bitwise but the values can be true or false any time.

How can I send multiple values to my new function which can be like this using bitwise?

`CONST CHECKNONE = 0;`
`CONST CHECKEMPLOYED = 1;`
`CONST CHECKRESIDENT = 2;`
`CONST CHECKDISABLED = 4;`
`CONST CHECKMARRIED = 8;`
`CONST CHECKALL = 15;`

How can I pass these values to my old function and check conditions ?

Comment: Are you asking how can you convert the bitwise values back to separate boolean values?

Comment: do you want to check if all of them are true?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: Yes, how can i send them to function and is it necessary to pass all values to function to check them?
Also can I skip false values to send back to function?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

const CHECKNONE = 0; 
const CHECKEMPLOYED = 1;
const CHECKRESIDENT = 2;
const CHECKDISABLED = 4;
const CHECKMARRIED = 8;
const CHECKALL = 15;

function checkPersonStatus($isEmployed, $isResident, $isDisable, $isMarried, $checkBit)
{
    if (!is_bool($isEmployed) || !is_bool($isResident) || !is_bool($isDisable) || !is_bool($isMarried))
        throw new \Exception("Invalid argument parameter");
    
    $employed = $resident = $disable = $married = 0;
    
    if ($isEmployed && ($checkBit === CHECKEMPLOYED || $checkBit === CHECKALL))
        $employed = 1;
    if ($isResident && ($checkBit === CHECKRESIDENT || $checkBit === CHECKALL))
        $resident = 2;
    if ($isDisable && ($checkBit === CHECKDISABLED || $checkBit === CHECKALL))
        $disable = 4;
    if ($isMarried && ($checkBit === CHECKMARRIED || $checkBit === CHECKALL))
        $married = 8;
        
    $check = $employed | $resident | $disable | $married;
    
    return $check === $checkBit;
}

$checks = [
    'check_all_true' => checkPersonStatus(true, true, true, true, CHECKALL),
    'check_all_false' => checkPersonStatus(true, true, true, false, CHECKALL),
    'check_none_true' => checkPersonStatus(false, false, false, false, CHECKNONE),
    'check_none_false' => checkPersonStatus(true, false, false, false, CHECKNONE),
    'check_married_true' => checkPersonStatus(false, false, false, true, CHECKMARRIED),
    'check_married_true_with_other_bit' => checkPersonStatus(true, false, false, true, CHECKMARRIED)
];

var_dump($checks);
```

Outputs

```
array(6) {
  ["check_all_true"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["check_all_false"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["check_none_true"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["check_none_false"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["check_married_true"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["check_married_true_with_other_bit"]=>
  bool(true)
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to send false values back to function as well? I read we can sue pipeline and send only true values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.